# Grizzly Server with static content and REST resource

Tags: java, grizzly, jersey-2.0

I have a Jersey REST 2.5.1 service which is served through a Grizzly server. Everything works fine so far. I want to add some static content, which is also served through Grizzly and provided from my JAR file. Therefore I use [`CLStaticHttpHandler`](http://grizzly-nio.net/2013/08/grizzly-2-3-3-serving-static-http-resources-from-jar-files/). When I access static resources, such as my `index.html` explicitly (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/index.html`), everything works fine. However, when I try to access the root `http://localhost:8080`, I get a 404. The code looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// some configuration stuff here

JacksonJaxbJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
provider.setMapper(mapper);

ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig()
            .packages("my.restapi.package")
            .register(provider);

HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), resourceConfig);
HttpHandler httpHandler = new CLStaticHttpHandler(HttpServer.class.getClassLoader(), "/static/");
httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(httpHandler, "/");
```

As far as I can tell from debugging, `org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.CLStaticHttpHandler.handle(String, Request, Response)` never gets called. Any hints, how I can make the `index.html` accessible as default page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some wasted hours, I feel a bit stupid now, but the simple solution was, to specify a path in `BASE_URI` (`http://localhost:8080/api/` instead of `http://localhost:8080/`). Now, when accessing `/`, I get the `index.html` and the REST methods are under `/api`.

Comment: Yes, thats the way I use it.

Comment: @qqilihq where do you place the static folder ?

Comment: Within the project's classpath (afair I was using a maven project back then, so I put `/static` in `src/main/resources`).